# Are Apache httpd modules binary-backwards-compatible between versions?

Tags: apache2

Can i (for example) use mod_proxy of version 2.2.10 with an otherwise unchanged 2.2.8 apache distribution under windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Apache module ABI is stable across the 2.2 releases, but I wouldn't swear to it. What happens if you try?

Comment: It does work.
Turns out that the apache httpd-project guarantees forward compatibility and tries to maintain backwards-compatibility of the ABIs.